# xsp.extlib.convstate returns null

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have an Xpage application that uses the extension library where the xsp.extlib.convstate is 'null' for one of three users until they manually refresh page. All three users access application via RDP using Citrix and internet options are the same for all three. Trying to figure out why this would be happening. The application is only on one 9.0.1 server.

Comment: Is it when they first access the application? when is it null? ie how are you accessing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of the source code, if there hasn't been a conversationState initialised yet, the conversationState would not be initialised until either:

1. after the Render Response phase (in the phase listener: com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.layout.impl.ApplicationPhaseListener)

   ```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // $NON-NLS-1$
   public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
       if(event.getPhaseId()==PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
           // After the render phase, we save the conversion state
           ConversationState.saveInSession(event.getFacesContext());
       }
   }
   ```
2. in the setParent method of the UIApplicationLayout, and this seems to be guarded by a 'isRestoringState' condition, which means I don't think this would run on the first view of a page as there wouldn't be any state to restore.

   ```
   @Override
   public void setParent(UIComponent parent) {
       super.setParent(parent);
       if( null == parent ){ // removing parent
          return;
       }

       // TODO should move this initialization to initBeforeContents instead
       FacesContextEx context = (FacesContextEx) getFacesContext();
       if(null != context && !context.isRestoringState()) {
           ConversationState cs = ConversationState.get(context, FacesUtil.getViewRoot(this), true);

           // Initialize the conversation state
           // Set the current navigation path to the UserBean
           ApplicationConfiguration conf = findConfiguration();
           if(conf!=null) {
               String navPath = conf.getNavigationPath();
               if(StringUtil.isEmpty(navPath)) {
                   // If there isn't a navigation path that is defined, the use the default one
                   if(StringUtil.isEmpty(cs.getNavigationPath())) {
                       navPath = conf.getDefaultNavigationPath();
                   }
               }
               if(StringUtil.isNotEmpty(navPath)) {
                   cs.setNavigationPath(navPath);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

So this might explain why it wouldn't be initialised until the 2nd page view.
You could try forcing an initialisation of the ConversationState before you try to use it, maybe in beforePageLoad, by calling one of the com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.layout.ConversationState's get() methods.
Note the boolean parameter tells the method to create the ConversationState if it does not exist.
I don't do much ServerSide Javascript but I guess this works? The sentiment is correct.

```
#{javascript: com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.layout.ConversationState.get(facesContext, true); }
```

If you are doing it in java then:

```
ConversationState.get(FacesContext.getInstance(), true);
```

Does this sound like an explanation of why you are seeing your behaviour?

Comment: The application uses the OneUILayout so although your explanation gives something of a reason it doesn't make sense considering this behaviour is only occurring for 1 of the 3 users.

Comment: For the 1 user is it happening on every new page? or only for the very first page they load? do they all access the application by the same initial url?

Comment: They all do access via same url.  Since we have now removed the debug toolbar we can no longer see the conversationstate value.  Thanks for your answer